# How to load imageview by providing imgsrc in .java file in android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am currently involved in a project about hotels and restaurants. My database contains hotel IDs(1,2,3,...) and I need to load the images(image1,image2,...) of the respective hotels/restaurants for which I have to give the image src through .java file.The code that I used is :

```
    String icon="image" + h_id;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable","testing.Image_Demo");
    image.setImageResource(resID);
```

But, the problem is that the hotel image is not loading. I had gone through different questions in this site but the problem remains as it is. Does anyone have an idea to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is resID = 0 ? if yes, that means the resource is not found

Comment: Where are the image files in your project ?

Comment: @fiddler the image files are within the drawable folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following sample activity, which works fine if I have a "image.png" image file in the drawable folder:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

    String icon = "image";        
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName());

    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
    imgView.setImageResource(resId);

    setContentView(imgView);
}
```

}

Did you check that your package name is correct ?

Comment: Does the package name should be my project's package name or the package name of the service that provides getResources()? I'm new to java.Pls, clearify me.@fiddler

Comment: I think it should be your project's package name. Have you tried using  `getPackageName()` like in my example ?

Comment: Yeah, I used but it isnot working @fiddler                                String icon="hotel" + h_id+".jpg";
  Log.e("resID","resource ID"+icon);
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName());
  Log.e("resID","resource ID"+resID);
  image.setImageResource(resID);

Comment: You should not put the ".jpg" extension in the icon string. Try using `String icon="hotel" + h_id` only